# ggplot query or change plot limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, limits

I have a ggplot object returned by a function in an R package.  I want to add some elements to this plot before plotting it.  But, I do not know the plot limits.  Is there a way to query the ggplot object to find the plot limits?  Actually, what I'd really like to do is simply set new limits for subsequent plotting, but I understand this is not possible, based on discussions of the impossibility of plotting data against two different y-axes.

For example, say I want to plot a small rectangle in lower-left corner of plot, but not knowing the plot limits, I don't know where to put it:

```
p = function() return(ggplot() + xlim(-2, 5) + ylim(-3, 5) +
    geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=1, xmax=2, ymin=1, ymax=2)))
gp = p()
gp = gp + geom_rect(mapping=aes(xmin=0, ymin=0, xmax=0.5, ymax=0.5))
print(gp)
```

Answer (score 1):

In **ggplot2 3.0.0**:
`ggplot_build(gp)$layout$panel_params[[1]][c("x.range","y.range")]`

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]][c("x.range","y.range")]
```

Comment: Thanks.  That didn't work but led me to the following, which does:

ggplot_build(gp)$panel$ranges[[1]][c("x.range","y.range")]

Comment: probably different ggplot2 versions, feel free to edit